# Galaxy S4 Battery Drain

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I recently got an S4, and the battery drain is huge. I'm not even using it with a SIM card yet because it is that bad.

Over 10 hours, `Phone idle` used 36%,  and time on was 10 hours 29mins. The screen used 23% at 9mins 20s.

Any idea how to make this battery last longer?

Comment: There are some apps that can diagnose your problem and may help fix it. Check the play store.

Comment: Is it a new one or used? I think battery life time is over. If the handset is new, get it replaced under warranty.

Comment: Its a used phone just over a year old. I tested the battery on a work colleagues phone and it held a charge fine.

Comment: Does your phone get hot very often?

Comment: Occasionally it would get very hot yes.

Comment: Is Data always on? How old is the phone? Do you always charge with Mobile Data on? One of my friends had his S4's battery die(battery became fat and stopped fitting in the back). I think it's best to go to a service center and verify if the battery is past its lifel

Answer (score 0):

It's your apps and services running in the background. Try to kill as much proccesses as you can. I used to put different apps in pause mode just by hitting home button, and I noticed the battery draining like crazy.

I also killed lots of services in App Manager (All proccess tab). I found lots of useless services draining my CPU and battery. Try that.